# Symfony Forms ManyToMany Select Option not working

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am building a form in Symfony using ManyToMany like this:

> Faq entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *     targetEntity="XXX\AppBundle\Entity\LegalAndHelp\FaqGroups",
 *     inversedBy="faq"
 * )
 * @ORM\JoinTable(
 *     name="faq_groups_faq",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="faq_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="faq_group_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")}
 * )
 */
protected $faqGroups;
```

> FaqGroups entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(
 *     targetEntity="XXX\AppBundle\Entity\LegalAndHelp\Faq",
 *     mappedBy="faqGroups",
 *     cascade={"persist"}
 * )
 */
protected $faq;
```

Then I am building the form like this:

```
$builder
        ->add('faqGroups', EntityType::class, [
            'class'         => FaqGroups::class,
            'choice_label'  => function ($faqGroups) {
                return $faqGroups->getDisplayTitle($this->userLanguage);
            },
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('fg');
            },
            'placeholder' => 'admin.faq.choose.group',
            'constraints' => [
                new Count([
                    'min' => 1,
                    'minMessage' => 'blabla'
                ])
            ]
        ])
```

Now (being in the edit part) I have the object in the form populated and I should be able to see all the data including the `<select>` with the set value already selected. The problem is that when there is a select it does not display the set value. When I am changing this and add `'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => false,` then the selection is OK. But I want to see this as a select dropdown and not a multiselect or a checkbox option.

Comment: If you have a ManyToMany relationship surely you shouldn't you be using multiple => true ? I would look at the getter setter, hasser remover functions (these are used by your form entity) if your getter returns an array of values and your select field is expecting a single value this might be problematic. Do you catch my drift here ?. I would add a datatransformer on your select field and transform from array to string first value) and back from string to an array of 1 value. Hope this helps

Comment: yup. that is what i thought ... makes sense ... thanks.